# Re-number a list when a new entry is inserted

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file of numbered entries:

```
1. foo
2. bar 100%
3. kittens
4. eat cake
5. unicorns
6. rainbows
```

and so on up to some large number. Then after an empty line, a new block starts from 1.

I insert a new entry, replacing, say, 4. and I need to renumber all the subsequent entries in the block:

```
1. foo
2. bar 100%
3. kittens
4. sunshine <
5. eat cake
6. unicorns
7. rainbows
```

Comment: Are blocks contiguous, or is there a separator? (Even an empty line?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### VIM solutions

There's two solutions: one is via automating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> keypress over a selection, second is via executing a pattern replacement with `submatch(0)+1` over the selection. First the key automation.

Start by creating your list:

```
1. foo
2. bar 100%
3. kittens
4. eat cake
5. unicorns
6. rainbows
```

Insert an entry

```
1. foo
2. bar 100%
3. kittens
4. eat cake
4. sunshine
5. unicorns
6. rainbows
```

Position your cursor onto `4. sunshine` and from command mode press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> . This is visual selection till the end of file. You can also move the cursor to the end of a block in the usual ways.

Press `:` to enter command mode, and you will see this: `:'<,'>`  . Now type in the following:

`norm` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

What Ctrl-v and ctrl-A do, is they allow you to enter "exact" key, so it will change into `^A` , highlighted. This is basically saying `for all lines selected, execute in normal mode keypress Ctrl-A` , and Ctrl-A by default increments the number under cursor.  You will see the numbers change

#### Solution in action:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

---

Another way would be to select everything from the first repeated number like before( <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd> ), and go into command mode to execute:

```
:'<,'>s/\v(^\d+)\./\=(submatch(0)+1).'.'/
```

Comment: This is exactly the simple memorable answer that I was searching for and couldn't figure out!

Comment: I can't use/type Ctrl-A in vim because cntrl-A is mapped to another key for `tmux`. Is there a way to send the same command as `ctrl-A` to vim via vims command mode, so I dont have to type ctrl-A?

Comment: @alpha_989 Well, according to https://digitalronin.github.io/2016/06/28/vim-increment-column.html this guy types `Ctrl-a a`. Works on my end as well :)

Comment: @alpha_989 I've added another , command-mode solution.  That avoids typing Ctrl+a altogether

Answer (score 13):

You can always add your new entry with a `x. newentry` syntax and renumber everything afterwards with something like:

```
awk -F . -v OFS=. '{if (NF) $1 = ++n; else n = 0; print}'
```

- `-F .`: sets the field separator to `.`<sup>1</sup>
- `-v OFS=.`: same for the *output* field separator (`-F .` is short for `-v FS=.`).
- `{...}`: no *condition* so the code inside `{...}` is run for each line
- `if (NF)`, if the number of fields is greater than 0. With `FS` being `.`, that means if the current line contains at least one `.`. We could also make it `if (length)` to check for  non-empty lines.
- `$1 = ++n`: set the first field to an incremented `n` (initially 0, then 1, then 2...).
- `else n = 0`: else (when NF == 0) reset n to 0.
- `print`: print the (possibly modified) line.

<sub><sup>1</sup>The syntax is `-F <extended-regular-expression>` but when `<extended-regular-expression>` is a single character, that is not taken as a regular expression (where `.` means any character) but as that character instead.</sub>

Comment: this does the job for me :) I'd enjoy some explanation as I'm a beginner with `awk`

Comment: @Zanna, see edit.

Answer (score 6):

Maximum overkill (and complexity! and bugs!) can be had via the [Text::Autoformat](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Autoformat) perl module.

```
% < input                                                                    
1. foo
2. bar 100%
3. kittens
4. it is getting dark. there may be a grue
4. no seriously, it's getting dark
4. really, you should find a light or something.
4. are you even paying attention? helloooo
4. eat cake
5. unicorns
6. rainbows
% perl -MText::Autoformat -0777 -ple '$_=autoformat $_, { all => 1 }' < input
 1. foo
 2. bar 100%
 3. kittens
 4. it is getting dark. there may be a grue
 5. no seriously, it's getting dark
 6. really, you should find a light or something.
 7. are you even paying attention? helloooo
 8. eat cake
 9. unicorns
10. rainbows
%
```

Actual results will depend on the input, desired output, options passed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using basic shell tools, it can be done like this - it may even be simpler:

```
paste -d . <(seq $(wc -l < new.list)) <(cut -d . -f 2- < new.list)
```

I'll explain from out- to inside:

```
paste -d . file1 file2
```

creates output lines from the files as columns. `-d .` sets the separator to `.`, which will end up behind the new numbers.

```
commandA <(commandB)
```

starts `commandB` and presents the output as if it where a file to read from to `commandA`, which expects a filename as argument. (See command substitution.)

The second argument of `paste`, `<(cut -d . -f 2- < new.list)`, outputs the second column unchanged, each line from the second field on, which means starting after the `.`.

The first argument of `paste` creates the new consecutive line numbers: it firsts counts the lines using "wordcount lines": `$(wc -l < new.list)`, and uses this number to create a sequence of numbers from 1 to the count, with `seq 7`.

Comment: Oh, regarding the empty lines, that's right - I focused at the test case.  But regarding the `.` - it assumes that there is the `.` after the number; Later `.` on a line have no effect, because then line will be cut at the first separator, before field 2, only (`-f 2-` meaning field 2 and following) - and does not touch further separators not used for cutting. It handles them as port of the field. Regarding the newline separated sections, `csplit` (also from `coreutils`) seems right;  Roughly split at empty lines, apply abbove method, cat results together. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @don_crissti I see - the OP's example is not clear about it -  I looked at the example of @tring and got mislead by the consecutive `4., 4. 4.` lines. Let's see...

Comment: +1 very nice for the first block (as in example)... I need to play with `paste` and `seq` some more... I can do it easily in an editor counting the lines, but I want a way that doesn't break if the number I want to insert is NOT the line number >_<

Comment: If you use vim, you could run the command from vim on selected lines - if they are just few. (A script needs to handle that the input is read two times, using a tmp file or so.in a script) (I'm pretty sure it's possible without tmp file, but that uses really obscure shell features, maybe...)

Comment: It may be easier to do directly in vim, if you use that; The rectangular visual block selection would be useful for example: There is good advice on vim questions at http://vi.stackexchange.com/, of course!

Comment: :) I've found some good stuff over there, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

remove numbers: `cut -d" " -f2- < list.txt > temp.txt`

insert line to temp.txt

make numbers: `cat -n temp.txt| sed -e 's/^[ ]*\([0-9]*\)[ \t]*\(.*\)/\1. \2/' > list.txt`

Comment: @don_crissti why?